# Parents and Dietary Restrictions

Tags: food, ayurveda, diet, food-restrictions

I don't wanna make my parents' life hard, so I said I would follow scriptural dietary restrictions of not eating onion and garlic as casual food. I also stated that if scripture prescribes meat/seafood for protein I will consider eating it as an adult and if my health degrades from these restrictions I will switch back. They keep on mocking me for this. They say how eating meat is so bad, even though it frees the animal from its current body and allows it to attain a heavenly realm and possible human birth. These are people who don't eat meat due to scriptural/cultural restrictions, but break it when eating Garlic. They also say that one cannot follow all the restrictions in the present-day which is true, but I responded by saying whatever I can follow as an adult I will. Can someone using scripture one and for all settle this case on dietary restrictions for all Varnas?